How to deploy Node.js server on Vercel properly?
I am new in Next js and also in MERN stack; recently I have completed a mern stack LMS (Learning Management System) website using Next js for client (front end) and Node.js , Express, TypeScript for backend server. But I am unable to deploy it on Vercel. The tutorial I followed they deployed on Heroku back then but it is paid now. I am getting 404 error on Vercel. Also I am quite confused about my backend that how to name it, is it Node js server or Express.js , how would I name it? Also what are the good folder structures for this type of backend.
I am giving the github link also to have a idea of the server files.
https://github.com/nahinAbrar/CodeLoomAcademy

I tried to deploy following some medium articles but it didnot work. here is my
package.json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "educatumacademy",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "build/server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only server.ts",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "nahinAbrar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.11",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^2.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.4.0",
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.0",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "stripe": "^16.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.15"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "ts.check",
    "build",
    "add-build"
  ]
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext", 
    "module": "CommonJS", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node"]  
  }
}

vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "server.ts",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "server.js"
      }
    ]
  }


Make a vercel.json in the root directory of your server with the following content, make sure to rename your server.js file to index.js:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
}

After that,

open the terminal and install vercel CLI
after successful login, type vercel in the terminal.
Vercel CLI will ask Set up and deploy, press y in response.
The, vercel will ask, which scope do you want to deploy to? Select your desirable scope.
Enter your projects name.
Select ./ as root directory and dont modify default settings.
Vercel will deploy your server, you can open the link to see your deployment status.

